# StackOverflow error, View.inflate Exception

Tags: java, android, html, mobile, stack-overflow

i have a dashboard layout that has several images. When i run the app i get force close error and the error point to this line in dashboard avtivty where inflate the layout(i.e setContentView(R.layout.dashboard). I dont understand why. I used the same Dashboard layout with other images and all was fine. Now it has six images but much bigger in size. I don't know if this is the problem and how to solve this? thanks.
Here is my dashboardlayout.

```
<com.utils.DashboardLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_btn_general_knowledge"
    style="@style/DPDashBoardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/general_knowledge_icon_bg_selector"
    android:onClick="onGeneralKnowledgeClick"
    android:text="General Knowledge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_btn_brainteasers"
    style="@style/DPDashBoardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/brain_teasers_icon_bg_selector"
    android:onClick="onBrainTeasersClick"
    android:text="Brain Teasers" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_btn_movies"
    style="@style/DPDashBoardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/movies_icon_bg_selector"
    android:onClick="onMoviesClick"
    android:text="Movies" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_btn_sports"
    style="@style/DPDashBoardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/sports_icon_bg_selector"
    android:onClick="onSportsClick"
    android:text="Sports" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_btn_music"
    style="@style/DPDashBoardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/music_icon_bg_selector"
    android:onClick="onMusicClick"
    android:text="Music" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/home_btn_celebrities"
    style="@style/DPDashBoardButton"
    android:drawableTop="@drawable/celebrity_icon_bg_selector"
    android:onClick="onCelebritiesClick"
    android:text="Celebrities" />
```

Here is the error logcat:

```
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hussein.android./com.hussein.android.DashBoardActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:568)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at com.hussein.android.quizgame.DashBoardActivity.onCreate(DashBoardActivity.java:18)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     ... 11 more
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     ... 22 more
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.indexOfStateSet(StateListDrawable.java:274)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable$StateListState.access$000(StateListDrawable.java:253)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.onStateChange(StateListDrawable.java:95)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:306)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.<init>(StateListDrawable.java:70)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:749)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:728)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1694)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:581)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:162)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:787)
01-08 02:29:29.216: E/AndroidRuntime(4221):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Dr
01-08 02:29:29.327: D/dalvikvm(4221): GC_CONCURRENT freed 284K, 52% free 2749K/5639K, external 6582K/8020K, paused 7ms+7ms
```

Here is a one of my the drawables sports_icon_bg_selector.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sports" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sports" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sports_blue" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/sports"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of your XML drawables? It looks like the error has nothing to do with the Dashboard layout, but in your Button drawables (StateListDrawable)

Comment: @MarkRenouf, I edited the question as per your request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a circular definition of your drawables. One (or more) of your selectors references something that references the selector again. (Or perhaps it references itself.)

(In my opinion, the resource compiler should catch this, but it apparently doesn't.)

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion directed me to solve the problem. The problem was that i had named xml drawables with the same name as some of the images, as a result, the selectors were referencing in a loop So, when i renamed them, my problem was solved!

Comment: @Hussein Thanks for sharing what was wrong. These errors can be subtle, which is why I think the compiler should catch them (or at least warn about them).

Comment: Yes, i also think the same, funnilly, the compiler didn't "complain" at all.